# .on('click') won't work on first click

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle

I can't get my code to work on the first click, however on the 2nd click it seems to work, I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and here is my code:

```
$('nav #mobileMenu').on('click', function(){
    var isToggled = $(this).data('isToggled');
    if(isToggled){
        $("nav#menu").addClass("mobileMenuActive");
        $("nav ul").fadeIn(1000);
        $("nav em").fadeOut('fast');      
    } else {
        $("nav#menu").removeClass("mobileMenuActive");
        $("nav ul").fadeOut(1000);
        $("nav em").fadeIn('fast');   
    }

    $(this).data('isToggled', !isToggled)
});
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try once with setting `isToggled` i.e. `$('nav #mobileMenu').data('isToggled', false).on(....`

Comment: sorry but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by doing this:

```
$('nav #mobileMenu').click(function() {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("mobileMenuActive")) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("mobileMenuActive");
        $(this).parent().find('ul').fadeOut(1000);
        $(this).parent().find('em').fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass("mobileMenuActive");
        $(this).parent().find('ul').fadeIn(1000);
        $(this).parent().find('em').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```